# How to invoke a function and pass parameter when you have function name as string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How to invoke a function when you have function name as string? e.g.

```
$scope.ExecuteFunction = function (func,val) {
  // here func="GetActivityInfo" and val="ERF000000000A6543"
  // How to Invoke function named in variable func and pass val as parameter ?
  // GetActivityInfo(val) to be invoked.
}

var GetActivityInfo = function (elementId) {
  // some code       
};
```

Comment: Global functions are properties of the global object (i.e. `window` in a browser). So `window[func](val)` should do the trick

Comment: ensure you don't have parenthesis for func.

Comment: `GetActivityInfo` is a private property of its parent function. It can only be accessed by [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). It can not be accessed by a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors). It needs to be made a property of an accessible object.

Answer (score 1):

If the function is in scope of the `window` you can use this:

```
window[func](val);
```

Comment: I am getting this error. window[func] is not a function

Comment: In that case the function is not in scope of the window. the logic works though - you just need to use the right parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`apply() or call()`** for achieving it,

**`var test = func.apply(test,val);`** this line should be added

**Definition:**

---> With `call()` or `apply()` you can set the value of `this`, and invoke a `function` as a new method of an existing object.

**Difference between `call()` and `apply()`:**

---> call() takes the function arguments separately, and apply() takes the function arguments in an array.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var myObject, myArray;
function myFunction(func,val) {
    var test = func.apply(test,val);
}
function myFunction2(val) {
    alert(val)
}
myObject = myFunction(myFunction2, ['myArray called using apply ']);      // Will return the value called from inside using `apply`
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObject; 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above snippet**

Comment: `will return 20`? Also I'm not sure this is answering the question, OP indicated the function to be stored as a string in a variable. There is no string containing the function name here.

Comment: @MarcCompte, thanks, my apologies, the comment is from the original documentation, form which that function is taken, the comment is changed, the comment may be wrong but, the answer is correct. :)

Comment: func="GetActivityInfo" and val="ERF000000000A6543". Both are string values. @Sravan my question was I have function name as string which is retrived from DB. I want to invoke that function in JS.

Answer (score 0):

please ensure you don't have parenthesis in parameter, try below in browser console :

```
function addUser(id, callback) {
    callback(id);
}

function callback(id) {
    alert(id);
}

addUser(1, callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

`GetActivityInfo` is a private property of its parent function. It can only be accessed by [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). It can not be accessed by a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors). It needs to be made a property of an accessible object:

```
var accessibleObj = { GetActivityInfo: GetActivityInfo };

$scope.ExecuteFunction = function (func,val) {
  // here func="GetActivityInfo" and val="ERF000000000A6543"
  // How to Invoke function named in variable func and pass val as parameter ?
  // GetActivityInfo(val) to be invoked.
  accessibleObj[func](val);
}

//var GetActivityInfo = function (elementId) {
function GetActivityInfo (elementId) {
  // some code       
};
```

In the above example the private variable (initialized to an anonymous function) was changed to a private function so that it could be [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting).